Trouble with Chrome Extension in Manifest V3: Executing Script in to Fetch Translation from Google Translate
I'm working on a Chrome extension that allows users to highlight a word, right-click to translate it using Google Translate, and then log the translation pair to Chrome's local storage. I have included Google Translate in both permissions and host_permissions (and have tried each individually), but I keep encountering the following error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
I am wondering if visiting an external website in background.js is allowed, or if only local hosts are permitted. I wanted to use the detect-language feature in Google Translate, but given that Chrome storage is limited to around 10MB, it doesn't seem feasible to include a neural network for detecting and translating multiple languages.
Is there any other way to work around this issue without building my own backend for it?
Thank you in advance for your help!
This is my code after reading Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host. In manifest 3:
I wanted to use the detect-language feature in google translate, this is just a minimum viable(not so much) product
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "translateToEnglish" || info.menuItemId === "translateToChinese") {
    const word = info.selectionText;
    const targetLang = info.menuItemId === "translateToEnglish" ? "en" : "zh-CN";
    const url = `https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=${targetLang}&text=${word}&op=translate`;

    (async () => {
      const newTab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: url });
      const tabId = newTab.id;
      if (!newTab.url) await onTabUrlUpdated(tabId);
      const results = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId },
        func: fetchTranslation
      });
      if (results && results[0] && results[0].result) {
        const translation = results[0].result;
        console.log(`Translation to ${targetLang === "en" ? "English" : "Chinese"}:`, translation);
      }
      chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
    })();
  }
}); 



You probably look at an old error and at the wrong console. Click the trashcan icon to remove it. Use devtools for the background script to debug the code.

Thank you, I can see the background script now. But for some reason, I can not find the logs of an async method. My fetchTranslation is like this: async function fetchTranslation() {
console.log("running")
try {....}catch(error){return ....} and it returns the result for catch the error. I cant find the "running" log in devTools and cant really see the error, I guess it is because it is async?

fetchTranslation runs in the website and prints in that tab's console.

That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!
